# How can I add choices to a timefield in a Django form?

Tags: django

In one of my models I have the following:

```
time = models.TimeField()
```

In a modelform based on this model I want `time` to be a dropdown with a few choices, so I tried this:

```
time = forms.TimeField(label="time", choices=[(datetime.time(0, 0), "Midnight"), (datetime.time(12, 0), "Noon")])
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'
```

Do I have to put choices in my model's timefield or is there a way to be define it in the form ?

Comment: will you only have 2 choices in your field?

Comment: @Lemayzeur No, it will probably be 24 hours with 5 minutes intervals.

Comment: So you want to display a list of hours in a dropdown list like `select` tag?

Comment: Yeah exactly like that.

Comment: In that case, why not using `forms.CharField()` with a `forms.Select()` as widget, where you can add a list of choices?

Comment: I will try that. Do I have to use ```CharField``` in my ```model``` too for ```time```, to make it work ?

Comment: Since all the values are pre-defined in your select options like `23:05` `12:34`. You just need to convert values to time object with python `datetime` and save it to model, you don't really need to change your model. Make sure that the values coming from users are really in the format needed

Answer (score 6):

Model:

```
import datetime as dt
begin_time = models.TimeField(default=dt.time(00, 00))
```

Form:

```
import datetime as dt
HOUR_CHOICES = [(dt.time(hour=x), '{:02d}:00'.format(x)) for x in range(0, 24)]

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'begin_time': forms.Select(choices=HOUR_CHOICES)}
```

and that's it really. The result is a pull down for the users showing the 24 hours (so no messing with input fields and users entering all sorts of silly stuff) and the result is a TimeField straight into the database.

Extra: if None is allowed change the model to:

```
    begin_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and the choice list:

```
HOUR_CHOICES = [(None, '------')] + [(dt.time(hour=x), '{:02d}:00'.format(x)) for x in range(0, 24)]
```