# Half Hours choice fields for TimeField in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to have field choice in form that user can pick hours with half hours choice.
I have this model and this `TimeField`:

```
class Sample:
   start_time = models.TimeField(choices=global_vars.TIME_MAP_HALF_HOURS_CHOICES,)
```

I want to show half hours time to customer. This is my Choices:

```
TIME_MAP_HALF_HOURS_CHOICES = (
    (datetime.time(00, 00, 00), '00:00'),
    (datetime.time(00, 30, 00), '00:30'),
    (datetime.time(1, 00, 00), '01:00'),
    (datetime.time(1, 30, 00), '01:30'),
    (datetime.time(2, 00, 00), '02:00'),
    (datetime.time(2, 30, 00), '02:30'),
    (datetime.time(3, 00, 00), '03:00'),
    (datetime.time(3, 30, 00), '03:30'),
    (datetime.time(4, 00, 00), '04:00'),
    (datetime.time(4, 30, 00), '04:30'),
    (datetime.time(5, 00, 00), '05:00'),
    (datetime.time(5, 30, 00), '05:30'),
    (datetime.time(6, 00, 00), '06:00'),
    (datetime.time(6, 30, 00), '06:30'),
    (datetime.time(7, 00, 00), '07:00'),
    (datetime.time(7, 30, 00), '07:30'),
    (datetime.time(8, 00, 00), '08:00'),
    (datetime.time(8, 30, 00), '08:30'),
    (datetime.time(9, 00, 00), '09:00'),
    (datetime.time(9, 30, 00), '09:30'),
    (datetime.time(10, 00, 00), '10:00'),
    (datetime.time(10, 30, 00), '10:30'),
    (datetime.time(11, 00, 00), '11:00'),
    (datetime.time(11, 30, 00), '11:30'),
    (datetime.time(12, 00, 00), '12:00'),
)
```

But When I want to save object, the form not validate and raise error: `Choose a valid option.`
How can I fix this error‌?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `TimeField` it is more preferred to set choices in `Form` rather than in the model.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54388572/12520350) on setting time choices in form using custom `Select` widget (rather than `forms.TimeField`).

Also, format of `TIME_MAP_HALF_HOURS_CHOICES` suggests it to be used with `forms` field choices (cause it contains `value` - `representation` tuples), not with `model` field choices (which uses `key` - `value` tuples). This may result in the error. Also, time representation does not seem like a model concern - it may have list of allowed datetime.time objects, but how to represent these values - views and forms can decide better.