# I want user to be able to book for the same table but not at the same time

Tags: django

I have a model caled BookTable and a model Table, i want users to be able to book for the same table but not at the same time but i have no clue how am i going to make it.

My BookingTable model...

```
class BookingTable(models.Model):
    TIME_CHOICES =[
        ('08:00', '08:00'),
        ('09:00', '09:00'),
        ('10:00', '10:00'),
        ('11:00', '11:00'),
        ('12:00', '12:00'),
        ('13:00', '13:00'),
        ('14:00', '14:00'),
        ('15:00', '15:00'),
        ('16:00', '16:00'),
        ('17:00', '17:00'),
        ('18:00', '18:00'),
        ('19:00', '19:00'),
        ('20:00', '20:00'),
        ('21:00', '21:00'),
        
    ]
     
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.TimeField(default='00:00', choices=TIME_CHOICES)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("list_tables")
       
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.user.username + "-" + self.table.name
```

My Table model...

```
class Table(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    size = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media/images/', default='static/media/images/default.jfif')
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, default="This is a very beatiful table")
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name[:50]
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("list_tables")
```

I don't know where to start from

Comment: You could define [two fields unique as couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201598/how-to-define-two-fields-unique-as-couple). In your case, add `constraints = [ models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['table', 'time'], name='name of constraint')]` to your `BookingTable` model.

Comment: in this case do i need to delete the existing table and time field?

Comment: No. But you need to `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a constraint to you model; as follows:

```
class BookingTable(models.Model):
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['table', 'time'], name='unique_username_email')
        ]
```

For this kind of issue costraints and validators are almost always the solution.
You can learn more about constraints here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/constraints/

And more about validators here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/validators/

Comment: I see but now i'm having another issue, when i pick up the time it gives me an error saying "Select a valid choice. 10:00:00 is not one of the available choices."

Comment: @lertonjosine This is because you are using a TimeField for selecting the time. Can you share the Form you are using?

Comment: @lertonjosine This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164326/how-can-i-add-choices-to-a-timefield-in-a-django-form might contain the answer to your new problem.

Comment: I got it, i just needed to convert the value in the list to time

Comment: @lertonjosine For more support remember to always check the documentation. If my answer was useful mark it as accepted so people with similar issues know this worked for you.